# Stuck with Import .CSV unknown attribute ''

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Got an error when i was clicked import .CSV File

[Click Here for see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmCkm.png)

Thanks you everybdy !

Answer (score 1):

I received the same error. It turns out in the CSV, there was data in a column that had no header and didn't map to any field I had in my Rails app. It contained comments that I never picked up on.

I had to add a new column to the application called 'comments' and create a new migration based on that.
Then went back into my CSV, added the header of 'comment'. Then it imported properly.

The import methods had found the data, but didn't know what column to add it to since there was no header in the CSV. So it gave an error, it doesn't know what '' is (no header).